# Sorted list not displayed correctly in riot v2.6.7

Tags: riot.js

I have problems displaying a sorted list in riotjs v2.6.7
I created a sample where every 3s a list of objects is modified, then sorted and displayed with riot.

https://jsfiddle.net/cristi_salcescu/86qc1vpy/

```
var addEditList = function(){ 
        that.items[2] = { fname: generateString() + "UPDATE" };
        that.items[4] = { fname: generateString() + "UPDATE" };
        that.items.push({ fname: "new" + generateString() });
        that.items.push({ fname: "new" + generateString()});        
    }

setInterval(function () {
        addEditList();
        that.items = _.sortBy(that.items, function(o) { return o.fname; });   
        that.update();
    }, 3000);
```

In v2.4.1 it works ok.

https://jsfiddle.net/cristi_salcescu/Lx0y5e9j/

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the no-reorder option in the each loop. Lately there were a lot of changes in how loops works to improve performance.

```
  <div>
    <div no-reorder  each="{ items }">{ fname }</div>
  </div>
```

Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/KN5gqEaUdB25RLsRG5Qz

pd: plunker is a little more riot.js friendly, use this to create example code http://riotjs.com/examples/plunker/?app=bug-reporter

Comment: Yes it works with no-reorder.
Good then I'll use plunker for other code samples.